# Concatenate argument to update a certain array with Angular/JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to pass in a string from one of my functions that will let another function know which array to update within another array. All the attempts I've tried end in poor errors that really don't lead me anywhere productive so far.

```
function likeFeedItem(itemId, feedItemIndex) {
  postActionsService.likeFeedItem(itemId)
    .then(function success(response) {
      var resource = 'capabilities.chatterLikes';
      ctrl.testUpdate(response.data, feedItemIndex, resource);
    })
    .catch(ctrl.showError)
};

function testUpdate(feedItemData, feedItemIndex, resource) {
  ctrl.feedResult.elements[feedItemIndex] . resource = feedItemData.resource;
  // Output should work/look like this would
  ctrl.feedResult.elements[feedItemIndex].capabilities.chatterLikes = feedItemData.capabilities.chatterLikes
}
```

Comment: If you are making use of AngularJS, I don't see any controller or services there. Please show the running code so that one will be able to understand better.

Comment: @Shashank turned out not to be relevant, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

`ctrl.feedResult.elements[feedItemIndex] . resource = feedItemData.resource;`

To:

```
resource = resource.split('.');
ctrl.feedResult.elements[feedItemIndex][resource[0]][resource[1]] = feedItemData[resource[0]][resource[1]];
```

EDIT: Also removed AngularJS tag as this doesn't have anything to do with it specifically.

EDIT2:

If you have an unknown amount of keys, you can loop like so:

```
resource = resource.split('.');
var current_node = ctrl.feedResult.elements[feedItemIndex];
for (var i = 0, n = resource.length; i < n; i++) {
    current_node = current_node[resource[i]];
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Brand new the angular so wasn't sure. Added the same resource to the other side of your answer since it needs to be there as well.

Comment: I approved the edit.  I didn't know if `resource` was actually a key for feedItemData or the same one, haha, so I left that one alone.

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense. Thank you again for your help

Comment: any recommendations for if the argument (`resource`) is an unknown length? It could be `capabilities.chatterLikes` or could be `capabilities.comments.page.items`?

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide an example using a `for` loop.

Comment: I hate to say but I cannot figure out how this works on the other side of my declaration. `ctrl.feedResult.elements[feedItemIndex] = current_node;`

Comment: You'd essentially have to duplicate the `current_node` and `for` loop.  So you'd do the second one as `var current_node = feedItemData;` and then go from there.